# Spring, Thymleaf and lists of strings

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Okay, I a wet-behind-the-ears newcomer to Spring and Thymleaf. I'm trying to do something so simple it should be a no-brainer. But I can't get it to work. The simple question is - how do you show a list of strings in an web page?

I have the following model

```
import java.util.List;
public class TestModel {

    private List<String> list = null;
    private String content;

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public List<String> getList() { return list; }

    public void setList(final List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

My web page contains the following:

```
<div th:if="${greeting.list != null}">
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <ul>
    <th:block th:object="${greeting}" th:each="item : ${list}">
     <li th:text="${item.name}">Item description here...</li>
    </th:block>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I added the ".name" to "item" only because I found a couple of examples where they had a list of strings and did something similar. But they had the ".name" on the object.

But it still doesn't work. The unordered list ends up empty. I.e. There isn't any list items inside the unordered tags.

What *am* I doing wrong? Pointers gladly accepted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since there's no example of filling model I supposed you put some strings into instance of `TestModel`'s list field like this.

```
TestModel greeting= new TestModel();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
model.addAttribute("greeting", greeting);
```

Then there are more errors in your Thymeleaf template example.

1. If you are using object selection through `th:object` you must at first place use asterix `*` to access object properties. Asterisk syntax evaluates expressions on selected objects instead of context variables map.
2. Object selection affects only children nodes in DOM.
3. In your example you want iterate over list of strings (`List<String>`) but you want to access property `name` which in fact don't exists on Java `String` object.

You must fix your Thymeleaf template in one way - see examples.

**No object selection at all**

```
<div th:if="${greeting.list != null}">
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <ul>
       <li th:each="item : ${greeting.list}" th:text="${item}">Item description here...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Proper object selection**

```
<div th:if="${greeting.list != null}">
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <ul>
    <th:block th:object="${greeting}">
       <li th:each="item : *{list}" th:text="${item}">Item description here...</li>
    </th:block>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Both examples worked. Thank you for setting me straight.

As I said - I'm *very* new to thymeleaf syntax. I have yet to find a good tutorial describing when to use what. I copied an example from another site but it did not work.

Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi its ok, I hope my example help you with this problem. I can recommend official Thymeleaf documentation. It's easy to read and full of examles. There's also some tutorials on official site. Check http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<table th:object="${userList}" id="userTable" border="1">
    <tr th:each="user :${userList}">
        <td  th:text="${user.getName()}"></td>
        <td  th:text="${user.getEmail()}"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another example using table and Object. Might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In thymeleaf, if you are looking  to create in a template a list of strings and compare it with a string, you can use the following structure.

```
th:if="${#lists.contains({'RO', 'UK', 'DE', 'BE'}, #session.getAttribute('country'))}"
```